# How to send a variable value to a POST form

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

In php :

```
$nom_du_formulaire = basename ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

after submiting a FORM and many many hoop in pgp files, i need the name of the original file that send it...So i try to get the $nom_du_formulaire when processing $_POST values...

i try this... not working

```
<input type="hidden" name="nom_du_formulaire" value="$nom_du_formulaire">
```

I try to use php global variable... dont work either !

SO the question, how to send my $nom_du_formulaire to a distant php file

files : in form.php : post = make_email.php. in make_email.php there is send_email.php
and i need $nom_du_formulaire in send_email.php. but if i ask $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] i get : make_email.php. not the form.php name i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you outputting the hidden tag? This is basic - You have to specify the PHP variable in PHP code if it's not already in a PHP code block.

```
<input type="hidden" name="nom_du_formulaire" value="<?php echo $nom_du_formulaire' ?>">
```

Or if it is you can output via print or echo:

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="nom_du_formulaire" value="'.$nom_du_formulaire.'">';
```

Try to avoid using global variables if possible.

Comment: Try to avoid using global variables if possible. : EVERYBODY said that... but never explain why...